# array javascript

Tags: javascript, array

I have the following nested array than i want to display in a Aura datatable ListOne (and ListinnerOne), ListTwo and ListThree, I'm trying to extract each list but I'm facing to this dificulty to understant how to do that, i'd tried the following but of the return of the LstInnerOne is undefined, could you help to solve this. Thanks

```js
let LstOne = []; 
let LstInnerOne = [];

for (let i =0 ; i < arr.length; i++){
    LstOne.push(arr[i].ListOne);
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].ListOne; j++){
        LstInnerOne.push(arr[i].ListOne[j].ListInnerOne);
    }
}
```

```js
let arr = [
    {
        "ID": 9165,
        "Folder": "LT102562",
        "Nome": "MICHAEL",
        "ListOne": [
            {
                "ID": "31",
                "IssueID": "3150",
                "ListInnerOne": [
                    {
                        "CodF": "123456",
                        "IDCard": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
                    },
                    {
                        "CodF": "123457",
                        "IDCard": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "ListTwo": [
            {
                "CodPessoaF": "3118101",
                "CodPessoaJ": null
            },
            {
                "CodPessoaF": "3118102",
                "CodPessoaJ": null
            },
        ],
        "ListThree": 
        [
                { "codListThree": "1" },
                { "codListThree": "2" },    
       ]
    }, 
    {
        "ID": 9166,
        "Folder": "LT102750",
        "Nome": "RACHEL",
        "ListOne": [
            {
                "ID": "35",
                "IssueID": "3150",
                "ListInnerOne": 
                [
                    {
                        "CodF": "123456",
                        "IDCard": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
                    },
                    {
                        "CodF": "123457",
                        "IDCard": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
                    }   
                ]
            }
        ],
        "ListTwo": 
        [
            {
                "CodPessoaF": "3118101",
                "CodPessoaJ": null
            },
            
                "CodPessoaF": "3118102",
                "CodPessoaJ": null
            },
        ],
        "ListThree": 
        [
                { "codListThree": "1" },
                { "codListThree": "2" },    
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: You'll see one problem by comparing your `i` loop's `<` condition with your `j` loop's `<` condition. Arrays have a length whether nested or not.

Comment: Note that basic debugging is easy to add; add `console.log` calls into your code and watch the results in the Console of your browser's Developer Tools. You can also set breakpoints and examine the data but that is for later.

Comment: Thank you for your advice